# AS3 How to remove elements from an array using splice()

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, splice

I am new to programming in general and making a snake game. I have three fruits in the stage, one for adding into the length of the snake using an push(), while the other will remove using splice(). I'm not sure what I am doing wrong since it's not displaying an error, so I will post the code. Is splice even the right method for this case?

```
var partsArr:Array = new Array(); //holds Snake’s head and body parts

function attachNewPart():void

{

    var newPart:Sprite = new BodyPart();

    addChild(newPart);

    partsArr.push(newPart); //add 1 part into snake body
}


function removePart():void

{

    var newPart:Sprite = new BodyPart();

    removeChild(newPart);

    partsArr.splice(newPart, 5); //removes 5 parts from snake body

    newPassFood(); // generate new remover food

}
```

Edit: So i changed function removePart() which now disconnects from the main body but doesn't hide the last part.

Here is the code:

```
function removePart():void

{
    var spliced:Array = partsArr.splice(-1,5);
    var newPart:Sprite = new BodyPart();

    addChild(newPart);
    newPart.visible= false;
    spliced.visible= false;

    newPassFood();

    // some code i tried but didn't work

    /*
    for (var i:int = partsArr.length-1;i > 0; i--)

    {

        partsArr.splice(i, 5);
        removeChild(newPart);
        removeChild(newPart);
        removeChild(newPart);

    }
    */

    /*
    if (partsArr.splice (partsArr.indexOf(newPart) == 1)) 
    //removes 5 tiles from snake body
    {
        removeChild(newPart);
    }
    */


    /*removeChild(partsArr[5]);*/

    /*removeChild(newPart);*/


}
```

Edit: Once again, i changed function removePart() which now disconnects 5 parts from the main body but doesn't hide them. Instead of using splice(), i'm now using pop().

Here is the code:

```
function removePart():void

{
    /*var spliced:Array = partsArr.splice(-1,5);*/

    var spliced:DisplayObject = partsArr.pop();
    var newPart:Sprite = new BodyPart();


    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();

    addChild(newPart);
    spliced.visible= false;

    newPassFood();
}
```

Comment: You need to work on your **OOP** understanding. Let's think in apples and a basket. First method: you take a new apple, put it into the basket and register it on your list. Totally correct. Second method: you take a new apple (again) and try to remove it from the basket (it never was in it) and cross it out of your list in a wrong way (the first 2 arguments of **splice** are numbers, not objects: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice() ).

Comment: Hello, i've just realized i forgot to call in the function at all, so that's why function removePart wasn't working no matter what i did. Thanks again!

Comment: I've encountered another problem where the last part of the array stays in the stage, and I can only remove the last part of the array, I think i'll post this problem in another thread.