# AS3 How to put a function within a Sprite and then hide the sprite?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, splice

I am a beginner programmer, making a snake game with some added features; there's a feature where I would like to remove 5 parts of the snake when it eats a certain food. So far with my attempts, i've made it work. However, the removed parts of the snake won't disappear. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158421/as3-how-to-remove-elements-from-an-array-using-splice) to my previous question for more context.

I've used array.splice(); to no avail, so I opted to use array.pop() instead, and pop() worked just fine, although i'm not so sure about it's efficiency, but it works!

Here is my current code with my hidden previous code:

```
function removePart():void

{

    var spliced:Sprite = partsArr.pop();



    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();

    removeChild(spliced);
    spliced.visible= false;

    newPassFood();


    //what i've tried previously

    /*var spliced:Array = partsArr.splice(-1,5);*/
    /*var newPart:Sprite = new BodyPart();*/
    /*addChild(newPart);*/
    /*newPart.visible= false;*/
    /*
    for (var i:int = partsArr.length-1;i > 0; i--)
    {

        partsArr.splice(i, 5);
        removeChild(newPart);
        removeChild(newPart);
        removeChild(newPart);

    }
    */

    /*
    if (partsArr.splice (partsArr.indexOf(newPart) == 1)) //removes 5 tiles from 
        snake body
    {
        removeChild(newPart);
    }
    */


    /*removeChild(partsArr[5]);*/

    /*removeChild(newPart);*/


}
```

I'm not even sure if var spliced:Sprite = partsArr.pop(); makes sense as turning a function into a Sprite, please help.

Edit: this is what my code looks now.

```
function removePart():void

{

    var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var removearray:Array = partsArr.pop();

    container.removeChild(removearray);


    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
    partsArr.pop();
}
```

Comment: Have you read a) that exciting article about display list and hierarchy and b) something about OOP principles, per my advice?

Comment: @Organis i've read more on the array, where it isn't possible to make an array as a display object. 

As i saw your comment, i reread the article about display lists, and had another go at coding function removepart() to no avail. I guess i still don't understand it well. I also haven't read about OOP yet, I'll see what I can do after I sleep. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry for being straightforward, but you lack understanding what are data types. Programming is not magic. If the **removeChild** method requires a **DisplayObject** argument, which is also a child of the given context, you cannot replace the argument with an **Array** and hope it magically works. If you need to remove 5 objects, you need to remove **EACH** of them, one by one, both with **removeChild** and from your **Array**.

Comment: @Organis i still don't fully understand that I cannot mix arrays with display objects, do you have another analogy on how to approach containing data types (arrays) within display objects?

Comment: I'm reading up on loops,  is this a step in the right direction? https://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/as3-loops-while-vs-for-vs-for-each/

Comment: The analogy is the same. There is stage (basket). Everything you put on stage (into basket) is displayed (it can have properties **.visible = false** or **.alpha = 0** so that the object cannot be seen, but it is still **displayed**). You can have display containers (boxes) on the stage (inside the basket) that can contain several other items or be just empty. Then, you have data structures (registry) that contain plain data (like numbers or texts) or references to the items and boxes, whether they are inside the basket, or elsewhere.

Comment: You can add, remove and arrange items in the basket, but data structures help a lot to address the objects and boxes in the basket. That's the point. First you devise the logic, then you build the display list hierarchy according to this logic.